# Passing variable value as function argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I get the value of `list` `code` elements?

```
def test(argu):
print(argu)

code = [5,10,15]
length =len(code)
for i in range(0,length):
   test("code[%d]" %i)
```

Expected output:

```
5 
10 
15
```

Acutal output:

```
code[0]
code[1]
code[2]
```

Comment: I'm surprised you know this much python without knowing you could just do `test(code[i])`

Comment: Opps! such a silly question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%` simply substitutes the parameter into the string, the string is not re-interpreted as an expression.

Just use an ordinary list index, without quoting it:

```
for i in range(0, length):
    test(code[i])
```

There's also no need to use `range`, just iterate over the list directly:

```
for elt in code:
    test(elt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing `test("code[%d]" %i)` by `test(code[i])` solves your problem:

```
def test(argu):
    print(argu)

code = [5,10,15]
length = len(code)
for i in range(length):
    test(code[i])
```